# Replace Variables with data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am very new to design a SMS/Email templates.
My Sample Created Template is :

```
   Dear Customer {first_name}{last_name}, 
Your Complaint Register Id is: {ID}, 
We will get Back u Soon
```

Here, `{first_name}{last_name}` are the variables. So I need to replace these variables with the data.How could i know what are the variables present in my template and then replace with corresponding data. Please help me.
Thanks...

Comment: give us example with what you expect as output

Comment: @Abdulla thanks for reply. I am expecting output like this  " Dear Customer ravi P , Your Complaint Register Id is: UOU123443, We will get back u soon".

Comment: You should accept the awnser of @Harsh Sanghani , this is the correct way of doing it. All you need to do is replace the variables in $replace with the variables that contain the right data. Also keep in mind that the order of the array does matter.

Answer (score 3):

You have to parse that template first then try following code :-

```
$search = array(
            "{first_name}",
            "{last_name}",
            "{ID}"
        );

$replace = array(
            $data['firstname'],
            $data['lastname'],
            $id
        );

str_replace($search, $replace, $parse_template);
```

It may help you.

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it, this allows users to create their own emailing templates.

Comment: I actually happen to use this myself aswell a couple days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$message = "Dear Customer $first_name $last_name, Your Complaint Register Id is: $id, We will get back u soon.";
```